# C++ WinSock Get Data From PHP Page?

Tags: php, c++, sockets, web, connection

Hello I'm quite new to using `sockets` and am not that familiar with them yet, Basically all i am trying to do is pass a `string variable` to a `web address` (e.g. `www.example.com/index.php?Example=StringExample`) and then get a response, so for example it would return `"Test Example"` if `index.php` looked like this:

```
<?php

if($_GET['Example'] == "StringExample")
{
    echo "Test Example";
}

?>
```

Here is what I've tried in c++:

```
struct sockaddr_in SocketAddress;
hostent* addr = gethostbyname("www.example.com/index.php?Example=StringExample");
int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
SocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr->h_name);
SocketAddress.sin_port = htons(80);
SocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 

SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); 
if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0) 
{
    return 0; //Failed to Connect
}

char buffff[256];
recv(Connection, buffff, sizeof(buffff), NULL);
//"Test Example" now stored in    buffff
```

What am i doing wrong?

Btw in my case i would not like to use any `libraries` like `boost` or anything like that. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4):

```
gethostbyname("www.example.com/index.php?Example=StringExample");
```

"www.example.com/index.php?Example=StringExample" is not a valid server name. This is an entire URL; a server name would be "www.example.com". `gethostbyname()` takes the name of a server, and not a URL, and returns its IP address. Additionally, `gethostbyname()` has been obsoleted. New code should use the [getaddrinfo(3)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/getaddrinfo.3.html) function, instead.

This is obviously an `HTTP` URL. To download a document via HTTP it is a lot more work than just connecting a socket. Establishing a socket connection is just the first step in the process of downloading a document from an HTTP server. This must be followed by sending a valid HTTP request, and then receiving an HTTP response from the server.

There are many libraries, such as [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), that implement the entire client-side process needed to download an HTTP document, that will handle the socket connection themselves.

But there's nothing wrong with trying to implement this yourself, either. It's a good programming excersize.

So, after resolving `www.example.com`'s IP address, you will need to

1) Connect to the server's port 80, the default HTTP port.

2) Send an HTTP request for "/index.php?Example=StringExample".

3) Parse the HTTP response.

The specification for HTTP requests and responses is defined by [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), which you can consult for complete documentation of how HTTP requests and responses are structured.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a web server with sockets, you have to keep in mind:

- You can open a tcp/ip connection to your web server
- BUT afterwards you have to do the http protocol by yourself

In case of your example:

```
hostent* addr = gethostbyname("www.example.com");
//...
const char* request = "GET index.html"
send(Connection, request, strlen(request), NULL)
//fetch index.html with a recv and parse it
```

To be more precise, if you want to access your server, you have to take a look how GET, PUT, POST, etc. are implemented in the http protocol, send the proper commands to your web server and recv() the replies